# Change the scrollbar speed upon mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar, mousewheel

Is it possible to change the scrollsbars speed upon scrolling using the mouse wheel for a element in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/V3aaN/2/ (**Edit: May cause seizures or epilepsy**)

**CSS:**

```
#smallBox {
    height:400px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
#whee {
    height:20000px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="smallbox">
        <div id="whee"></div>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
    var thing = $('#smallBox');
    var extra = 100;
    var old = $(thing).scrollTop();
    $(thing).scroll(function() {
        if ($(thing).scrollTop() < old) {
            $(thing).scrollTop($(thing).scrollTop()-extra);
        } else if ($(thing).scrollTop() > old) {
            $(thing).scrollTop($(thing).scrollTop()+extra);
        }
        old = $(thing).scrollTop();
    });
```

Comment: Once again, many thanks! But how can I affect the scroll for a element like `#whee`? It seems like it doesn't work to replace `window` to `'#whee'` :/

Comment: Well you would need the parent of #whee to have a scrollbar first. Check out my update.