# Controlling Jquery scrolltop speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

I have this code for moving the box using .scrollTop. Using this i code i was able to move the box from bottom to top, is there any other way to control the speed of scrolling every 100 pixel?

Here's my **jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var x = $(document).scrollTop();
        var dh = $(window).innerHeight();
        var move = x / 100 * 100;
        console.log(x);
        $('.box').css('bottom', move);
        }
    });
});
```

and the **css:**

```
body {
    height: 2000px;
}
.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f00;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance guys. Have a nice day.

Comment: speed of what exactly?

Comment: Speed of scroll ms kitty.

Comment: So you have this http://jsfiddle.net/c8sFu/1/ what you expect to happen?

Comment: is that what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407918/change-the-scrollbar-speed-upon-mouse-scroll

Comment: Something like that but the scroll amount should be 100s

Comment: This is what i want to do, 100px per scroll.
http://darsa.in/sly/examples/parallax.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are getting at, if not, please be more specific as to what you are asking for.  That said....

```
var move = x / 100 * 100;
```

Just change the numbers in the denominator.  It alters the rate of scroll.