# Reduce/fix scrollspeed on Website (js)

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am making a scroll based website for a school project. Det problem is that the site looks realy bad if people scroll down fast. Is there a way to fix / set a max scroll speed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Change the scrollbar speed upon mouse scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407918/change-the-scrollbar-speed-upon-mouse-scroll) shows a pretty good solution (you'll probably want to remove the background-color changing!)